# C# linq IEnumerable update item

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have IEnumerable activeContents need to update one element.
but when I try to put it back (activeContents = cm;) it's not working i get the same list.

how can I solve this?

```
ContentModel ActiveContent = contentToAction;
List<ContentModel> cm = activeContents.ToList();
    cm.Remove(ActiveContent);
    ActiveContent.seq = seq;
    cm.Add(ActiveContent);

    activeContents = null;
    activeContents = cm;
    activeContents = activeContents.OrderBy(con => con.seq);
```

I read some articles here but didn't found how to solve it.

Comment: Why wouldn't you get the same list? You're adding and then removing the same item. Could you explain more what the problem is?

Comment: i'm changing the item , I can't make chnges in the IEnumerable

Comment: You can make changes in an Enumerable, just not in a for loop. If that is what you are doing use an indexed loop instead.

Comment: can you add an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the context of this code? Are you passing `activeContents` in as a parameter? Also, what is the declaration of `ContentModel`? Is that a value type (struct) or reference type (class)?

If `ContentModel` is a class, then you don't need to add and remove the element to change the `seq` property (I hope that's a property…public fields are icky :p ). Just find the element in the list and change the element that's already in there. Even better if the `contentAction` value is in fact already the instance that's in the list.

As for the larger problem, based on what little information you've provided, it seems likely that the code looks something like this:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    // These are initialized somehow:
    IEnumerable<ContentModel> activeContents = ... ;
    ContentModel contentToAction = ... ;
    int seq = ... ;

    UpdateSequence(activeContents, contentToAction, seq);
}

void UpdateSequence(IEnumerable<ContentModel> activeContents,
    ContentModel activeContents, int seq)
{
    ContentModel ActiveContent = contentToAction;
    List<ContentModel> cm = activeContents.ToList();
    cm.Remove(ActiveContent);
    ActiveContent.seq = seq;
    cm.Add(ActiveContent);

    activeContents = null; // superfluous in any case
    activeContents = cm;   // ditto here
    activeContents = activeContents.OrderBy(con => con.seq);
}
```

If that's the case, then to address your question, your code should look more like this:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    // These are initialized somehow:
    IEnumerable<ContentModel> activeContents = ... ;
    ContentModel contentToAction = ... ;
    int seq = ... ;

    UpdateSequence(activeContents, contentToAction, seq);
}

IEnumerable<ContentModel> UpdateSequence(IEnumerable<ContentModel> activeContents,
    ContentModel contentToAction, int seq)
{
    List<ContentModel> cm = activeContents.ToList();
    cm.Remove(contentToAction);
    contentToAction.seq = seq;
    cm.Add(contentToAction);

    return cm.OrderBy(con => con.seq).ToList();
}
```

The above assumes `ContentModel` is a struct. If it's a class and you are guaranteed that the `contentToAction` object is already in the `activeContents` list, then this version would also work:

```
IEnumerable<ContentModel> UpdateSequence(IEnumerable<ContentModel> activeContents,
    ContentModel contentToAction, int seq)
{
    contentToAction.seq = seq;

    return activeContents.OrderBy(con => con.seq).ToList();
}
```

Finally, I'll point out that if `activeContents` is normally being stored as a `List<T>` anyway, then treating it as an `IEnumerable<T>` here only hurts. You might as well take advantage of its `List<T>` nature and sort it in-place, if that's the case.